# Number Theory Square Root of Non-Prime Mod

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to figure out $\sqrt{15}$ of $Z^*_{35}$ and $Z^*_{17}$? I do know how to compute the sqaure root for $Z^*_{17}$ since its a mod of odd prime and I got the answer 7, but I don't know how to compute it for the case $Z^*_{35}$ and any help or idea would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can at least check the answer yourself.  $7^2=49=15$ modulo $17$, so $\sqrt{15}=7$. Similarly, $15^2=225=15$ modulo $35$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $15$ and $35$ have the common factor $5$, and so we set out to eliminate it.

Start with

$x^2\equiv15\bmod35$

Because of the common factor we know that $x\equiv5y$ for some $y$.  So then

$25y^2\equiv15\bmod35$

And now divide by the factor of $5$.  Since the modulus shares this factor we have to divide it by $5$, too, thus

$5y^2\equiv3\bmod7$

Multiplying by $5^{-1}\equiv3\bmod 7$ gives

$y^2\equiv9\equiv2\bmod7$

which should be easy to solve.  Then back substitute $x\equiv 5y\bmod 35$ to finish.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details! This makes sense!